# C++ Unions in the Memory

Tags: c++, unions

I am fiddling with a code like following:

```
union Data { 
    int i;
    double x;
    std::string str;
    ~Data(){}
};

union Data var = {.x = 31293.932};

std::cout << var.x << "\n";
std::cout << var.str << "\n";
std::cout << var.i << "\n";
```

As far as I know, the union have some 64 bit thing written after I set x member to some floating point number. Then I want to see corresponding string, asuming I treated those bytes as char. But I am getting segmentation fault when I try to print it as string. Why is that? I initialized the union so I assume var.str must be initialized as well.

Comment: Basically, throwing a bunch of bytes into a memory slot and hoping that you can treat those bytes as a valid `std::string` object is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: You're expecting putting the members into the union magically enables them to convert from any data type to any other data type, and that's not how things work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str` is not constructed. if you must use `str` you must either provide a constructor for it or construct it via placement new. A full example below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

union Data
{
    int i;
    double x;
    std::string str;
    Data() {}
    Data(std::string st) : str(st) {}
    ~Data() {}
};

int main()
{
    Data var;
    var.x = 31293.932;
    new (&var.str) std::string("Hello World!");


    std::cout << var.x << "\n";
    std::cout << var.str << "\n";
    std::cout << var.i << "\n";

//destroy it
    var.str.std::string::~string();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Just to expand my answer a bit...

MSDN seems to have a n00bie friendly explanation about unions than cppreference. So, check: [Unions - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxy4b7b.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [Unions - cppreference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dxy4b7b.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: What does "new (&var.str) std::string("Hello World!");" really does? Does it allocate memory with size "Hello World!" or it just calls the constructor for Data?

Comment: Worth adding that since `i`, `x`, and `str` share the same space in memory, assigning to `i` or `x` after setting `str` will corrupt `str` and possibly render it undestroyable.

Comment: @meguli That's a Placement New. Read more here: [What uses are there for “placement new”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `char` to access the bytes in the union. `std::string` is not a POD type and can't be used in this way.

Try this instead:

```
union Data { 
    int i;
    double x;
    char bytes[sizeof(double)];
    ~Data(){}
};

union Data var = {.x = 31293.932};

std::cout << var.x << "\n";
std::cout.write(var.bytes, sizeof(var.bytes));
std::cout << "\n" << var.i << "\n";
```

The full definition of what a POD type is extensive. In very simple terms it is a basic data type without a explicitly-defined copy constructor, destructor, or virtual methods and does not itself contain any such types if it is an aggregate type (like struct, class, and unions).

Comment: Recommend a quick expansion on POD (Plain Old Data) to help the poor newbs.

Comment: @user4581301 Good suggestion although the full definition of POD is quite complicated. I added a little blurb about it to get someone started, though.